# find column and row index on specific regex match on a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe with string content in its cells.

What's the best way to find a string that matches an specific regex and then return a list of tuples with their respective row and column indexes?

I.e.,

```
import pandas as pd
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'a':['hello', 'world'], 'b': ['hello', 'folks']})

def findIndex(mydf, regex):
    return regex_indexes
```

If I do:

```
regex = r"hello"
findIndex(mydf, regex) # it'd return [(0,0), (0,1)],
```

If I do:

```
regex = r"matt"
findIndex(mydf, regex) # it'd return [(-1,-1)],
```

If I do:

```
regex = r"folks"
findIndex(mydf, regex) # it'd return [(1,1)],
```

I could do a double for loop on the `pd.DataFrame` but was wondering if other ideas are better...

Comment: A double loop won't be necessary. Wouldn't `None` be better for no match?

Comment: @AntonvBR good call, yeah None would also work and probably a better idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `apply`, `str.match` and `nonzero`.

```
def findIdx(df, pattern):
    return df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(pattern)).values.nonzero()

findIdx(mydf, r"hello")
(array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]))
```

- `df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(pattern)).values` return an array of the same size of `df` where `True` indicates matches and `False` otherwise.
- We then use `nonzero` to find the indices of `1`(`True`) part.

It will return the indices that match the pattern in a tuple of arrays. If you need 
a list of tuples, use `list(zip(*findIdx(mydf, r"hello")))`

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1)]
```

or `np.transpose(findIdx(mydf, r"hello"))`.

---

If one needed to return `None` while nothing is found, one can try

```
def findIdx(df, pattern):
    ret = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(pattern)).values.nonzero()
    return None if len(ret[0]) == 0 else ret
```

---

Note: `str.match` uses `re.match` under the hook. It will match a string which *begins with `pattern`* in this example function. If one wants to find whether a string contains `pattern` as a substring, use `str.contains` rather than `str.match`.

Comment: thanks this is def in the right direction.  I have a follow up q though, it doesn't seem to behave as a typical regex.  If I do findIdx(pd.DataFrame({'a': ['br', 'a hello,'], 'b':['das','hello']}), r"hel"), it will only match the one on row 1, col 1 but not the one on col 0... any suggestions on how to write the pattern part for more general cases?

Comment: @Dnaiel I think perhaps you use `str.contains` if you want to find whether a string contains a substring.

Comment: `.to_numpy().nonzero()` will be required as of [version 0.24.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.nonzero.html)

Comment: FWIW, In a "real" application of this, the thing doesn't work as expected unless NaN in dataframe are coded as false.  So I change to `return df.apply(lambda x: x.str.match(pattern, na=False)).to_numpy().nonzero()`.